# Which Stack Exchange site should be used to ask a question about Microsoft Teams Administration through PowerShell?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about Microsoft Teams administration and PowerShell. I am not quite sure which Stack Exchange site the question would apply to.

It could apply to SharePoint - since Teams is related to SharePoint. However, it is not exact. On the other hand, I suppose it is more related to SharePoint than just the general Super User site.

Is there a general Microsoft/Office Administration page that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is your best bet. Here is an example question that seems to be very similar sounding to what you are trying to do:

- [Using PowerShell to Assign Teams Policies to Users](https://superuser.com/questions/1531825/using-powershell-to-assign-teams-policies-to-users)

Take a look at the [Super User tour](https://superuser.com/tour) for more information.